# Is it possible to update a specific child's value without ID or key in firebase realtime database from android on button click?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[this is my database and now I need to change the value of favorite from 0 to 1 but I don't have any specific id so how can I change specific child's value on click in android!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y6pM.png)

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Is there any screenshot or picture of the DB?

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: In addition to adding the JSON (as text, no screenshot), which you get by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data), also be sure to include what you **do** know about the child node you're trying to update.

Comment: i added my db screenshot here u can check it now and if is there any possibility to update my data than plzz help

Answer (score 1):

In order to update a node, you must know the complete path to that node.

Firebase does not support the concept of *update queries*, where you can pass a condition to an update statement. So if you don't know the complete path, you will have to take a two-step approach:

1. [Perform a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) to find the node(s) to update.
2. Update each node.

Say that for example the `Name` property identifies the nodes you want to update, you could do that with:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cameras");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("Name").equalTo("TheNameOfTheNodeYouWantToUpdate");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot cameraSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            cameraSnapshot.getReference().child("Favorite").set(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Given that you're updating a counter in the above, you'll actually probably want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) inside that `onDataChange`:

```
DatabaseReference favRef = cameraSnapshot.getReference().child("Favorite");

favRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Integer currentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
        if (currentValue == null) {
            mutableData.setValue(1);
        } else {
            mutableData.setValue(currentValue + 1);
        }

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Transaction completed
        Log.d(TAG, "transaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```